# 'named' service keeps crashing in a VPS server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, redhat, service, bind

I'm not sure but I think the named service keeps crashing on my VPS server.

This brings it up fine:

```
root@vps [~]# /sbin/service named restart
```

How can I diagnose why this is happening?

```
root@vps [~]# uname -a
Linux vps.example.com 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in `/var/log/messages` for the output from your named process as it starts and fails.

You can also run named directly from the command line and switch on debugging to get more information on what is happening. Depending on how you have configured named you may have to supply other command line parameters e.g.

- -u user to run named under
- -c /path/to/named.conf
- -t /path/to/chroot

To run named in the foreground and send all logging to stderr

`/usr/sbin/named -g`

To run named in the foreground and send all logging to stderr with additional debugging information

`/usr/sbin/named -g -d 1`

You can increase the debug level to get more verbose logging.

Answer (score 0):

Check named process:

```
ps aux | grep name
bind     15133  0.0  0.4 279224 59612 ?        Ssl   2010   1:18 /usr/sbin/named -u bind
```

Check port listen:

```
lsof -i udp:53
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
named   15133 bind  512u  IPv6  96328476       UDP *:domain
```

Check log:

```
less /var/log/(syslog|named.log|message|daemon.log|...)
```